# How to target specific class inside cascaded classes and ids

Tags: css, class

I am trying to find out the rule on how to target a class inside cascaded ids and classes so that I will be able to style specific area of a page when I need to modify things. Specifically wordpress child themes.

I have search for a while and so far results are giving me specifics to a particular situation. I like something general that will help me read html and target specific classes to style.

For example in this HTML.

```
<div class="one-third">
    <div id="nav_menu-4" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    <h1 class="title">
        <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="About " style="width: 72px; height: 24.05px;">
        <canvas width="91" height="27" style="width: 91px; height: 27px; top: -2px; left: -1px;"></canvas>
        <cufontext>About </cufontext>
        </cufon>
        <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="us" style="width: 27px; height: 24.05px;">
    </h1>
    <div class="menu-about-us-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to change font of H1 Title when it is within a side bar. I tried this but didn't work.

```
.one-third .title {
  font-family: Impact;
}
```

What is the rule/formula to get specific selector to target specific classes.

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/9C3XD/ this is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try using a **selector** before the pseudo-class, see:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

On CSS Syntax

Answer (score 0):

you need to add h1 tag `.one-third h1.title {font-family: Impact;}`